# iPhone launch image orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, launch

My iPhone app supports landscape left and right orientations, but the launch image is not oriented according to launch orientation. Is there a way to fix this? I'm using Retina Display and iOS 4.x. There seems to be more options available on iPad, like using Default-LandscapeLeft/Right.png etc., but iPhone app doesn't seem to load those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orientation based Default.png images are only supported on iPad application but not in the iPhone aplication whether you are making for simple or retina display.

So, Default-LandscapeLeft/Right.png is only limited to the iPad apps. In iPhone applicaiton you can only set the Default.png for portrait orientation only. And not possible for any other orientation.

Let me know if more help needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge concern it is not possible to do the orientation for launcher images.